# C++ Matrix Class - Suggestions

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

I am trying to build a templated Matrix class in C++. Below is its implementation.
I implemented two operators +,+= as of now just to give an idea on how it will look and I thought it would be best to ask for feedback before I proceed any further.

The whole implementation is public and also there are no explicit bound/error checks, this is because its not meant to be a full fledged matrix library and hence avoided unnecessary code.

It would be very helpful if someone could comment on it and may be suggest a few improvements or suggestions.

Thank you.

```
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
    public:
    int r,c;
    vector< vector< T > >mat;

    Matrix() {}

    // Constructor to set the size of the matrix
    Matrix(int _r,int _c)
    {
        r=_r;c=_c;
        mat.resize(r);
        for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
            mat[i].resize(c);
    }
    // Constructor to build a matrix from a C 2d array
    // Pointer to the first element is passed (&arr[0][0])
    Matrix(T *arr,int _r,int _c)
    {
        r=_r;c=_c;
        mat.resize(r);
        for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
                mat[i].push_back(arr[i*c+j]);
    }
    template<typename U>
    Matrix<T>& operator +=(const Matrix<U>&M)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
                mat[i][j]+=static_cast<T>(M.mat[i][j]);
        return *this;
    }
    template<typename U>
    Matrix<T> operator +(const Matrix<U>&M)
    {
        Matrix<T>tmp=*this;
        return tmp+=M;
    }
};

template<typename T>
istream& operator >>(istream &in,Matrix<T>&M)
{
    in>>M.r>>M.c;
    Matrix<T>tmp(M.r,M.c);
    for(int i=0;i<M.r;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<M.c;j++)
            in>>tmp.mat[i][j];
    M=tmp;
    return in;
}
template<typename T>
ostream& operator <<(ostream &out,Matrix<T>M)
{
    for(int i=0;i<M.r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<M.c;j++)
            cout<<M.mat[i][j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return out;
}
```

EDIT:
Thank you all for the suggestions.

I just have one small question, say I do want to implement error checking (ex: checking for bounds,valid arguments etc..) however I do want the provide user with an option to disable error checking completely, is there any good way to implement this ?
What I need is something like example:`ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);.
Thanks again.

Comment: You're assuming that the dimensions of the RHS is the same as the LHS - this may not be intentional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points:

- Use a single `std::vector<T>` instead of `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`. Index it with y*r+x - use and operator overload to make this easier (see next point). This will be more memory efficient and slightly faster (and your init will be a lot easier: `resize(r*c)`).
- Make your data members private to protect your matrix against unintentional size changes. For example, user code can currently resize the vectors but leave the old `r` and `c`.
- Overload `operator()` to access the matrix (both const and non-const). If you really must use the `matrix[r][c]` syntax instead of `matrix(r,c)`, consider overloading `operator[]` and returning an iterator to the correct row (vector iterators are random access, so they will provide `operator[]`).
- Implement `operator+` as a non-friend non-member function instead - Improves encapsulation!
- Use initialization lists as others suggested.
- Let the constructor that currently takes a `T*` take an iterator instead. That way you automagically get the pointers support along with a lot of other cool things, such as range checking for debug-iterators, automatic type conversion for compatible value types and support for all other random access iterators. Also consider filling your matrix row-wise, so you can use forward iterators too.

Comment: Thank you. I compressed the matrix into a 1D vector and there was significant increase in speed. I just have one question though about point 3. Will there be any speed issues with either kind operator overloading. More specifically which of the three will be faster while accessing elements? 1. using matrix[i][j] 2. using matrix(i,j) or just defining an getter/setter functions like matrix.at(i,j) etc.. Thank you.

Comment: @jack_carver: If your compiler isn't shabby, it will all boil down to the same machine instructions, so there shouldn't be any speed differences. It seems that [][] might be a little harder to optimize (because it requires a temporary) - but I think any recent compiler will be able to optimize that away.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how it's done properly, see the Eigen project's implementation:

https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/49e00a2e570c/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h

https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/49e00a2e570c/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h

Eigen is a template-heavy fast matrix library for C++. I'm sure there's a lot of usefulness there.

Answer (score 2):

1 .Use initializer lists for constructor like, `Matrix (...) : r(_r), c(_c)`

2.`operator +` can be simply `{ return this->Add(M) }` (assuming that typenames `T` and `U` are compatible and you have implemented some Add() method).
3. If you are constructing something from 2D array then use below technique:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
public: // ...
  void Construct (T *arr)
  {
    mat.resize(r);
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
        mat[i].push_back(arr[i*c+j]);
  }
  template<size_t ROW, size_t COL>
  Matrix(T (&arr)[ROW][COL]) : r(ROW), c(COL)
  {
    Construct(arr);
  }
//...
};
```

Thus you don't have to pass the size of the 2D array when you are calling and it will reduce the probability of errors.

1. For better readability, you can use better names for class members: either `this->r` or `t_r`.

Comment: This constructor overload is pretty cool, but it cannot handle 1D arrays or generic iterators. +1 for cuteness tho :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But Wouldn't (*this+M) result in infinite recursion ?

Comment: @Itjax, 1D array can be handled in same way with putting 1 more overload like `template<size_t ROW> Matrix (T (&arr)[ROW]);`. For generic iterators we can put more overloads. @jack_carver ... I don't think `(*this + M)` will be infinite. I suggested it because you are returning by value from `operator +` & there is no need to make a copy in temporary. Thanks to both for appreciation.

Comment: I've defined += operator and reused this for the + operator. I've tried it, it gives segmentation fault.

Comment: @jac_carver, I am sorry for my mistake. You are right `(*this + M)` will lead to infinite loop. My point was that we should try to do some optimized way of adding 2 matrix like `this->Add(M)` inside `operator +`, so that we don't have to create a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Use initialization lists when initializing contructor args:

```
 Matrix(int _r,int _c)
    {
        r=_r;c=_c;
```

..

should be:

```
 Matrix(int _r,int _c) : r(_r), c(_c)
    {
        ....
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You might want to make `r`, `c` and `mat` members private.
2. Your streaming operators are not symmetric (`operator<<` doesn't write out `r` and `c`).

Comment: I agree on making `mat` private, however I'd like to be able to retrieve the dimensions of a matrix from the outside, so I'd keep them public (but make them const) or at least add some methods to get their values.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a vector of vectors to achieve this. This way you're adding quite some overhead to all lookups without any real need for it. Just allocate a one or two dimensional array of `T` and use that one within your class instead. This would also allow fast copying to other object instances without having to iterate through all fields as well as resetting the whole matrix.

Also you should make your members const when they shouldn't be changed later on (in your example `r` and `c`). To initialize them just use the constructor list in Tony's post.

Comment: What overhead are you adding to the lookup by using nested vectors? There’s a memory overhead to be sure, but no lookup overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You're wasting your time keeping `_r` and `_c` because the vectors keep their own sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you used the very expensive push_back function in this Class initialization:

```
// Pointer to the first element is passed (&arr[0][0])
Matrix(T *arr,int _r,int _c)
{
    r=_r;c=_c;
    mat.resize(r);
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
            mat[i].push_back(arr[i*c+j]);
}
```

Since you already have the number of rows and columns, consider this:

```
// Pointer to the first element is passed (&arr[0][0])
Matrix(T *arr,int _r,int _c)
{
    r=_r;c=_c;
    mat.resize(r);
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
        mat[i].resize(c);
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
            mat[i][j]= arr[i*c+j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If speed is what you have in mind, don't implement a matrix library yourself but use Boost libraries, I've used them in some projects and do pretty well on both 32 and 64 bit architectures

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Although having a fast implementation would be good, but speed isn't the primary concern here. I am implementing this because the need for such code arises quite frequently in programming competitions where external libraries aren't allowed.

Comment: Competitions are based on speed?

Comment: Two kinds, Mainly how fast you solve and submit the solution and then of course the efficiency of the code.

Comment: Then if you need maximum performances I'd recommend you using CUDA libraries with appropriate hardware. Anyway I don't really know how these competitions are planned so you might not be able to use that