# Zero out a section of a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array (a representation of a matrix). I need to zero out, not the entire array, but a section of it. What's the best method of doing this? I tried using memset, but it just gives me a typecast error.

**Example**

```
_matrix[row][column] = memset(
                        _matrix[row][column], 
                        0, 
                        sizeof(_matrix[row][column])
                    );
```

**Declaration**

`float** _matrix = new float*[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COL];`

Comment: Why would you assign the result of `memset`?

Comment: omg.  you should consider getting a good book on C/C++

Comment: What is the section you want zeroed out? A row? column? Rows and columns?

Comment: @Marlon what do you think?
I do have a good book on C/C++ - and I'm taking a class this quarter on it :P.

Comment: there is a host of problems with your snippet.  C++ has very large learning curve - and you have to understand memory layout and indexing.  you really should be asking more basic questions or read similar posts.

Comment: @Holland : He said a _good_ book. ;-] Which book are you reading?

Comment: cf:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633609/c-matrix-class-suggestions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076624/c-matrix-class

Comment: @ildjarn The OpenGL red book.

Comment: The OpenGL red book might be a good book on OpenGL, but it's not a good book to learn C++ from.

Comment: Would you have any suggestions? I'm looking for something which I can literally open up for a few minutes and scan through, rather than read from cover to cover. I'm passed the basics of programming - I just came from C#.

Comment: @Holland : See this thread: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/636019)

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter to `memset()` is the *address* of the location to zero. So:

```
memset(&_matrix[row][column], ...)
```

However, in your case the following would be far more straightforward:

```
_matrix[row][column] = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tagged as C++ yet you're not really doing any C++. Why not just do that? Avoid all the lower level memset and direct array nonsense.

I certainly think you should take some of the previous advice and really learn the underlying C, memory access, etc., but in C++ this could simply be avoided.

A quick line of code to get you on your way:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> > Array2D;
```