# c++ working with 2d arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

Currently I'm learning C++ and I've been trying to create a simple image processing library for learning purposes.

One of my features is eroding an image. As input it has two 2d arrays, and it returns another 2d array. All these arrays are of variable size. Let's give you an example of what I want to achieve.

```
int image[5][5] = 
{
 {'0', '0', '0', '0','0'},
 {'0', '1', '1', '1','0'},
 {'0', '0', '1', '0','0'},
 {'0', '1', '1', '1','0'},
 {'0', '0', '1', '0','0'},
 };

int kernel[3][3] = 
{
 {'0', '1', '0'},
 {'1', '1', '1'},
 {'0', '1', '0'},
 };
```

Then I want to pass them to my function (this doesn't compile, but it serves as an example of what I want).

```
int** erode(int image[][], int kernel[][]);
```

So far, I've read quite a bit about this. All I've read is that the columns can be of variable length, but the rows can't. So I should be change it to the following:

```
int** erode(int image[][5], int kernel[][3]);
```

But that's not really want I want either, because well, the image can be 10*10 and the kernel could be 5*5. So this isn't optimal in this situation either.

Then what I've read is creating a class, that internally stores the image as a 1d array and makes it look like a 2d array. Also I've read about using the `Boost.MultiArray` class to do this. But well I'm not too happy about that either. Because then I'm forcing the people that use it to also use those classes. And I think it's creating a lot of complexity for something that seems really simple (at least it is in C#)

To be honest, I can't imagine there isn't an easier way to do this. Optimally I'd say only use classes/methods from the standard `C++11` library. **How would you solve this problem?**

Timo

Comment: I guess nothing, but I was wondering if it couldn't be done without using external libraries. I guess it's also better for my understanding of pointers and arrays in C++ if I did it myself.

Comment: you can find multiple examples on SO, search for `c++ matrix class`.  eg:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633609/c-matrix-class-suggestions

Comment: Yeah I've found matrix classes, but coming from C# it just seems crazy to create a class for it, if you could 'just' use a 2d array. I understand C++ isn't C# but well...

Comment: c++ is pretty bare language per se as far as addons go.  it keeps you pretty close to metal - this is where  boost comes in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning a 2D vector  is less complicated.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef std::vector<std::vector< int> > vector2D;

int image[5][5] = 
{
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
     {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
     {0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
     {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
 };

int kernel[5][5] = 
{
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
     {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
     {0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
     {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
 };



vector2D  erode(int image[5][5], int kernel[5][5])
{
    vector2D image_process_data ;

    //create 2D vector array
    image_process_data.resize(5);
     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
     {
         image_process_data[i].resize(5);

     }

    //perform calculations
    for (int ix = 0; ix < 5; ix++)
    {
        for (int iy = 0; iy < 5; iy++)
        {
            image_process_data[ix][iy] = image[ix][iy] + kernel[ix][iy];

        }


    }        
    //return the 2D array
    return image_process_data;
}

int main( )
{
    vector2D new_image;

     new_image = erode(image, kernel);

    //display new_image
    for (int ix = 0; ix < 5; ix++)
    {
        for (int iy = 0; iy < 5; iy++)
        {
            cout<<new_image[ix][iy]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";

    }        



return 0;
}
```

How to set up a 2D vector array:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using std namespace;

#define HEIGHT 5
#define WIDTH 3

int main() {
  vector<vector<double> > array2D;

  // Set up sizes. (HEIGHT x WIDTH)
  array2D.resize(HEIGHT);
  for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i)
    array2D[i].resize(WIDTH);

  // Put some values in
  array2D[1][2] = 6.0;
  array2D[3][1] = 5.5;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this solution is that you don't have a contignous memory.

Answer (score 4):

see if you can use templates, eg:

```
template<int N>
void f(int (&arr)[N][N]);
```

if arrays have compile time bounds.
but really you should consider boost, armadillo, or tvmet

Comment: This still requires the size to be known at compile time, not runtime.  This may or may not be what the OP needs.

Answer (score 3):

I would pass the array as a pointer and also pass another parameter which defines the size of the array.

`int** erode(int* image, size_t imageSize, int* kernel, size_t kernelSize);`

An array is just a list of consecutive variables when in memory and the array variable such as `image[5][5]` just points to the first element of the array. To pass the arrays you have shown into the function you would use.

`int** ret = errode(image, 5, kernel, 3);`

Be careful when using this however because it could easily cause a segmentation fault but when used correctly, it will be fine. Also this assumes that the array is square, to overcome this limitation just pass in another parameter which describes the other dimension of the array.

**Update**

I see Anycorn has posted a very nice solution. His is a safer solution however will require you knowing the size of the array at compile time. If this is the case I would recommend you use what he has said.

Comment: Ah super that seems not too hard. Just a question, why do people prefer to use for example the boost classes, or create matrix classes for this?

Comment: Those classes remove any risk of memory corruption. This requires you to handle all the safety concerns whereas boost would do that for you.

Comment: those classes also make it so you don't have to do the coordinate math yourself.

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote about internally storing 1D array is essentially the best solution. Using 2-dimensional array is usually dangerous and can easily lead to errors. If you don't want to create whole class, consider:

```
const int SizeX = 10, SizeY = 10;
int Array[SizeX*SizeY];
inline int& Get (int x, int y) { return Array[SizeX*y+x]; }
```

Of course, it is the very simple example, but usually solves a lot of errors.

```
struct MyOwnArray
{
    int SizeX, int SizeY;
    int* Data;
    inline int& Get (int x, int y) { return Data[SizeX*y+x]; }
}
```

The code above will allow you to pass references to this struct in a convenient way. And it's only 6 lines of code!

Of course, the code above would need some more code; for example for allocating memory. However, if you carefully program all these parts, you will be pretty safe to use it and it should be well-protected from bugs.

Comment: Thanks for giving me this example, just for my understanding: how is using DrYap's code dangerous and how can it lead to a lot of errors. To me (a very newby c++ programmer) it seems fine xD But what's wrong with it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code itself, rather the conception behind it. If you give user (in this case, a programmer is a user) raw access to pointers, really bad things could happen. Just imagine you assure array size incorrectly. Your code won't break, instead, it will override some of your other memory. In the best case, OS should crash your app, in worst - you will spend hours looking for a bug in other part of your code. Encapsulating data structures in classes protects your data from corruption, as DrYap wrote.

Comment: I'd be happier if your 'get' function had an assert in it.

Comment: I didn't write it for simplicity's sake, and also noted, that it isn't complete in terms of usage in program.